# Failed to compress build artifacts: exit status 2

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, build, cloud-foundry

Error while pushing application to Cloud Foundry after the installation of packages.

Type of application: Next.js

Answer (score 1):

The app contained an updated buildpack for the node engine, deleting the deployed app from CF space and then re-deploying worked.